# ListView widget updates only when the screen size is changed by dragging the window (in Chrome and Windows apps)

Tags: flutter

I have used the following codes to list items based on data fetched from API:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foxChat/models/data_collection.dart';
import 'package:foxChat/models/user_model.dart';
import '../models/colors.dart';

class PeopleList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PeopleList({super.key});

  @override
  State<PeopleList> createState() => _PeopleListState();
}

class _PeopleListState extends State<PeopleList> {
  List<User> peopleList = <User>[];

  void fetchData() {
    UserData.fetchAllUsers().then((response) async {
      try {
        if (response.body != null) {
          Iterable list = await json.decode(response.body);
          peopleList = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();
          print(peopleList);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 500,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: peopleList.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 10),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.red,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 30,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage:
                                  AssetImage(peopleList[index].imageUrl),
                              radius: 29,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        peopleList[index].name,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Abel',
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 5,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        peopleList[index].lastName,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Abel',
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    peopleList[index].userId.toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Dosis',
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      // Text(
                      //   peopleList[index].creationDate,
                      //   style: const TextStyle(
                      //       fontFamily: 'Kanit',
                      //       fontSize: 13,
                      //       fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                      // )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 3,
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 65),
                    child: Divider(
                      height: 1,
                      color: CustomeColors.deviderColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 3,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

When I run the app, I can see data fetched from API in the console area but the `ListView` is empty. When I change the window size a little, the list is shown. I'm using the latest Flutter version (3.7.8). Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying the data fetching function:

```
void fetchData() {
    UserData.fetchAllUsers().then((response) async {
      try {
        if (response.body != null) {
          Iterable list = await json.decode(response.body);
          setState(() {
            peopleList = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();
          });
          print(peopleList);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }
```